# XCode Using TAB to tab multiple lines of code

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, customization, key-bindings

[image]Is it possible to select multiple lines of code in XCode and when I press `TAB` button all those selected lines indent?

I know `CMD+[` will indenet and `CMD+]` will undent. But I want that same principle to happen to 'TAB
`and`SHIFT+TAB`.

Right now, it just deletes the highlighted lines when TAB is used to the Structure Keybinding. I can't get my keybindings to work right. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replace the shift right [ with a tab and the shift left ] with Shift-tab.  Just double click on the present key binding and press TAB or Shift TAB.   However I've seen that Xcode doesn't always apply the settings right away so it wouldn't hurt to restart it.

Comment: In XCode 5 that creates conflicts with the normal Tab behavior. How did you resolve that and get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Xcode Preferences, under Key Bindings. You can search for the current bindings by typing "TAB" in the search field. You may need to delete some current bindings to get yours to be in effect.

Comment: Yep : look at the 'Conflicts'